# Huffman Coding Using Doubly Linked List

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, huffman-code

I am developing an implementation of Huffman Compression in x64 MASM. My main function in C syntax would be:

```
void* huffCompress(void* lpDataStream, unsigned long long qwLength);
```

I am using Microsoft's Fastcall convention where the paramters are passing to the called function using RCX, RDX, R8 & R9 (anything else is on the stack).

I have written code which generates an array of size 256*3. Each 3 byte consists of:

```
as STRUCT
    word wFreq
    byte bSymbol
as ENDS
```

The code then iterates over the lpDataStream twice.

1. Initialising bSymbol with the index in the array
2. Incrementing wFreq for each byte

In the code below RBX is a pointer to the base of the array, RSI is a pointer to the lpDataStream and RCX is qwLength. RAX needs to be 0 before entering the below code.

```
_populateArray:
    lodsb
    lea rdx, qword ptr[rbx+rax*04h]
    sub rdx, rax
    inc word ptr[rdx]
loop _populateArray
```

The function then iterates over the array and for each element which has a wFreq which is not zero it subtracts 13h (19 bytes) from the stack. These 19 bytes are then populated as per the following structure.

```
nl STRUCT
    qword pFLink
    qword pBLink
    dword dwFreq
    byte  bSymbol
nl ENDS
```

The first two qwords are forward and backward links to the next and previous elements in the linked list.

```
xor rax, rax
mov r10, rsp
mov rcx, rax                    ;rcx = pFLink
mov rdx, rax                    ;rdx = pBLink
_generateLinkedList:
    cmp word ptr[rbx+rax], 0000h
je _notInitialised
    sub rsp, 13h
    ;write and setup pBLink for next entry
    mov qword ptr[rsp+pBLink], rdx
    mov rdx, rsp
    mov r8w, word ptr[rbx+rax]
    mov r9b, byte ptr[rbx+rax+02h]
    mov word ptr[rsp+wFreq], r8w        ;write dFreq to linked list
    mov byte ptr[rsp+bSymbol], r9b      ;write bSymbol to linked list
    cmp rcx, 00h                        ;if pFLink is not initialised it means this is the first entry
je _firstEntry
    mov qword ptr[rsp+13h], rsp         ;when rcx != 00h it means that there is an entry before this one "before" on stack remember
_firstEntry:
    mov rcx, rsp
_notInitialised:
    add rax, 03h
    cmp rax, 300h
jna _generateLinkedList
```

The above code works as desired, I have added it for completeness. RBX is still pointing to the array.

The function then runs bubble sort on the resulting linked list, sorting in ascending order. This means the element with no pBLink (no backward link) has the lowest wFreq. It is not a circular doubly linked list.

The next step of implementing Huffman Compression is to create a node with a wFreq equal to the sum of the two lowest frequencies.

My plan for this was to do the following:

1. Add the two lowest wFreq values together
2. Make pFLink in the lowest element NULL
3. Make both pFLink and pBLink is the second lowest (pHead->pFLink) NULL
4. Make more stack space (19 bytes) and add a node to the end (this involves finding the element with a NULL pFLink and changing it to the new node. Additionally the new node has the wFreq of the two lowest added together.

**This is where the problem is.** I need to make the pFLink and pBLink of the new node point to the two lowest elements (The nodes which had their pointers NULLED in step 2 & 3. However if I do this then the new node cannot be connect to the linked list.

EDIT: I think the above option would work, I would have to rework the sorting algorithm so that when a new node is added and needs to be sorted it is inserted inbetween elements. The code would realise it has found a "new node" because the pBLink wouldn't be correct. It would then know the next element is directly "above" (19 bytes above the "new node"). I think this could be done during the new node creation as the new node doesn't **need** to be placed in the new space on the stack it can be swapped with the element which is at it's desired place. It's a dirty workaround, if there is a better way I would love to hear it.

I had the idea that when the sorting function finds a node where the pBLink doesn't point to the previous element it should just move up the next element by subtracting 13h from it's pointer. This didn't work because the new nodes (those created by adding the two lowest frequencies together) could be anywhere after sorting.

Is there any way to overcome this without adding two more qwords to the nl structure?

Comment: Why you need to make the  pFLink and pBLink of the new node point to the two lowest elements? A node in a linked list doesn't even need a pBLink unless you want to efficiently move backwards. Are you sure a linked list is what you need? a node cannot be in between two elements and at the end of the list at the same time. Maybe you need two lists?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I am reusing pFLink and pBlink to point to leaves of a node in the Huffman Tree. The code converts a linked list to a Huffman Tree. I included a pBLink because I need two pointers for the tree anyway so I may aswell use the second as a pBLink. I may traverse the linked list backwards when checking where a new node should be placed due to the fact that it's more likely the new node will need to be somewhere at the top (due to having a higher frequency). A nodes memory address and position in the linked list are independent.

Comment: Are you optimizing for code-size at the expense of speed?  If not, avoid the slow `loop` instruction unless you're only tuning for AMD CPUs.  [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52980461).  Also, `lodsb` is 3 uops, vs. 2 for `movzx` / `inc rsi` which avoids a false dependency on the old RAX.  You can also do `*3` as an index like `lea edx, [rax+rax*2]` / `add [rbx + rdx], 1`.  (But an indexed `add [mem], 1` will unlaminate into more uops than `add [rdx],1` on Sandybridge-family.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Neither at the moment. I will probably optimise for code size later. I never though of using "lea edx, [rax+rax*2]" that's really nice, thanks!

Comment: If you haven't seen that multiply-by-3 idiom before, there's probably a lot you can learn from looking at optimized compiler output.  Write some of your functions in C (with function args and return values for inputs/outputs), then look at gcc and clang `-O3` (pure speed including autovectorization) or `-Os` (code size and speed) output on https://godbolt.org/.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  If you really want to optimize for code-size, see [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981)

Comment: @PeterCordes That's a good idea I will try, I am using Visual Studio but I'm sure there will be similar switches. The hard part for me is knowing what to Google - "golfing" seems to be good.

Comment: To understand how to optimize for code-size, you should start by understanding how x86-64 machine code encodes instructions.  So read Intel or AMD's manual.  Optimizing by using fewer instructions / more efficient code is often really good before you start golfing those instructions for size, so have a look at Agner Fog's optimizing asm guide https://agner.org/optimize/ and other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: `mov word ptr[rsp+wFreq], r8w        ;write dFreq to linked list` looks broken.   `wFreq` is a member of `as`, not `nl`, so it's the wrong numeric offset.  Also, the definition you show shows it as a `dword dwFreq`, so you probably want to load it with `movzx r8d, word ptr [blah blah]` so you can store a dword.  And BTW, why not sort the array of 3-byte objects before making a linked list?  If you pad it to 4 bytes, you can copy data around with simple dword loads/stores.  And if you store it with the symbol at the low byte, the whole thing will compare correctly as an integer. (little-endian)

Comment: You use `bSymbol` twice, so I don't know how MASM is going to figure out whether `mov byte ptr[rsp+bSymbol], r9b` is `+20` or `+2`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not actually using the structs they are for my reference I actually have a few "EQU" statements at the top of my file. "pFLink EQU 00h
pBLink EQU 08h
wFreq  EQU 10h
bSymbol EQU 12h"

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't understand. I am using the byte read from the stream as the index in the array. I don't see how I can move anything around before writing the frequencies? I guess I could sort the array after putting all the frequencies in.

Comment: That's what I mean.  Count frequencies like you are now (but with padding to 4-byte structs the indexing is simplified), then sort that array before expanding it to include pointers.  qsort or merge sort are good simple algorithms for that kind of array size.  256 elements is larger than you want to use bubble sort on.  Or radix or bucket sort could be ok, but only 256 elements makes an O(n log n) algorithm fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay I like it. How do you recommend I expand it? I need to make need space on the stack for two pointers and a frequency. I then need to take into account both the array and any nodes that are on the stack? That's two place I need to look at to determine the next lowest two frequiences. Is it okay?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in speed, then you need to start with carefully considered algorithm choices before even remotely considering writing it in assembler. The correct choice of algorithms will make order of magnitude improvements. Then writing it in assembler may give you small factor improvements.

In particular you need a *much* better choice for sorting, likely quicksort in this case, and you can do the [Huffman coding much more simply, in place](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/14d8/356655dba66dce55a01a98bfa84e26cd2712.pdf), without re-sorting linked lists.

Comment: Moreover, writing in asm will only help if you're better at it than a compiler (unless the goal is to learn asm, rather than to create a fast and/or small implementation right away.)  Copying around 3-byte objects with separate word + byte stores doesn't look like a good start.  Like I suggested in comments, storing the symbol+count in a 4-byte object lets you compare the whole thing as an integer (x86 is little endian, so put the symbol in the low byte, count at the top).  Sorting on `(count << 16) | symbol` means you don't need to extract the count into a separate register to compare it.

Comment: I am writing this in assembler because I enjoy working with it. It is useful for me to learn as I enjoy CTFs and reversing. Speed is only a minor concern to me - learning assembly and how algorithms and software are implemented is my goal. I understand there are many improvements that could be made. I am using bubble sort in this instance because my understanding of Quick Sort is limited. As far as I know it requires recursion? This would probably end up impacting my programs stack pointer therefore messing up my linked list/array which are stored there.